# Speech to text, text to speech, audio on IOS - How to make it work

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, p5.js

I am creating an node.js web application using speech.js -speech recognition - p5js sound library - and multiple audios: a nightmare for IOS mobile.
I do am playing the audio after button click, made especially for Chrome but audio still does not work on mobile nor Ipad.

I have been looking up different question asked in the past years about it but they seem a little outdated by now and nothing really work. Is there any trick for it?

This is how my audio plays:

```
var buttonStart = document.getElementById("start");
buttonStart.onclick = function(){ 

var speechRec = new p5.SpeechRec('en-US', gotSpeech); // new P5.SpeechRec object
let continuous = false;

let interim = false;
speechRec.onEnd = restart;
speechRec.start(continuous, interim);
getAudioContext().resume();

function restart() {
  speechRec.start();
};

function init() {
  speech.speak("hello");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[iOS Safari and Safari doesnt support in browser SpeechRecognition](https://caniuse.com/#search=SpeechRecognition)

There is some [polyfill](https://github.com/anteloe/speech-polyfill)

It uses [Microsoft's Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/) API for that.

If you don't like it, you could use [Amazon Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/), [Speech-To-Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text), or set up your own API teach some neural model in tensorflow. Now question is how much effort, money would you like to put on stake.

Also even if you use polyfill [p5 seems to use only `webkitSpeechRecognition` object and it doesn't check any alternatives](https://github.com/IDMNYU/p5.js-speech/blob/master/lib/p5.speech.js#L245)

That means before `p5.speech` is loaded you'd have to initialize `webkitSpeechRecognition`

```js
window.webkitSpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition
```